# add_prompter() message blocked by infobox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to add a hover message using `add_prompt()`, but the message is partially blocked by the boundary of the `infoBox` itself. Is there a way to put this prompt message at the top?

```
infoBox(
              title = tags$span(
                HTML("<b>Info Box</b>"), 
                tags$span(
                  icon(name = "question-circle") 
                ) |>
                  add_prompt(message = "Message Here", position = "left")
              ), 
              subtitle = "subtitle"),
              value = 0
              width = 4
              color = "red",
              fill = F
            )
```

Screenshot attached.

[image]

I am trying to put this prompt message at the top, not blocked by the edge of the `infoBox()`.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)